# String Buffer Unit Tests Failing

Tags: java

I am trying to create a diamond and return the stringbuffer converted as a string. In the console i see what i am expecting. However my unit tests are failing. Please shed some light on to as why my tests are failing.

```
public class Diamond {
    public static String print(int n) {
        if (n <= 0)
            return null;

        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        int mid = (n + 1) / 2;
        int midIdx = mid - 1;
        int run = 1;
        while (run <= n) {
            char[] chars = new char[n];
            int delta = Math.abs(mid - run);
            for (int idx = 0; idx < mid - delta; idx++) {
                chars[midIdx - idx] = '*';
                chars[midIdx + idx] = '*';
            }

            buffer.append(rightTrim(new String(chars)) + "\n");
            run++;
        }

        return buffer.toString();
    }

    public static String rightTrim(String s) {
        int i = s.length() - 1;
        while (i >= 0 && s.charAt(i) != '*') {
            i--;
        }
        return s.substring(0, i + 1);
    }

    // public static void main(String... strings) {
    // System.out.println(print(3));
    // }
}
```

Unit Tests
    import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
    import static org.junit.Assert.assertNull;

```
import org.junit.Test;

public class DiamondTest {
    @Test
    public void testDiamond3() {
        StringBuffer expected = new StringBuffer();
        expected.append(" *\n");
        expected.append("***\n");
        expected.append(" *\n");

        assertEquals(expected.toString(), Diamond.print(3));
    }

    @Test
    public void testDiamond5() {
        StringBuffer expected = new StringBuffer();
        expected.append("  *\n");
        expected.append(" ***\n");
        expected.append("*****\n");
        expected.append(" ***\n");
        expected.append("  *\n");

        assertEquals(expected.toString(), Diamond.print(5));
    }

    @Test
    public void getNullReturned() {
        assertNull(Diamond.print(0));
    }
}
```

Comment: Where does it fail and what fails?

Comment: If you're interested, you might want to try out Hamcrest: `assertThat(Diamond.print(3), is(expected.toString()))`. This gives readable code, and the error messages in case of test failures also are more helpful.

Comment: Please also consider using `StringBuilder` instead, as `StringBuffer` is synchronized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `chars` array is not initialized (`char[] chars = new char[n];`).
Because of this the non-`*` characters are different from space (`' '`), namely the array contains null bytes instead. Initializing the array helps, for example using `Arrays.fill(chars, ' ')`.

Comment: Consider `Arrays.fill(chars,' ')`?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here.

```
char[] chars = new char[n];
```

You're initializing a string from a character array, which is full of `\u0000` (zero values) by default.

Yet in the test you are comparing with space characters (ascii value 32).

So you need to initialize the string with spaces instead. Here's a way to do it:

```
char[] chars = new char[n];
Arrays.fill(chars, ' ');
```